# Updating old project using Publish feature with new project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce

We've used the Publish feature in VS2012 for our VB.NET project, which is out to a lot of users.
We've now made a new project in C# (also VS2012) that's supposed to replace the other project and be called "v2".

Because this is a completely new project, what would be the process of having the old project update to the new project automaticly through ClickOnce, if this is even possible?

Comment: Is the current application set up to publish as an online only app or is it available offline(shows up on the start menu) as well?

Comment: Available offline as well.

Comment: not sure if you can do what you're asking, you may want to investigate uninstalling the old app or releasing a final version of the old app which somehow points to the new app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because this is a completely new project, what would be the process of
>   having the old project update to the new project automaticly through
>   ClickOnce, if this is even possible?

Yes it is possible. Just use the same assembly name, product name and url. Obviously you also need to increase ClickOnce version of your application.

Comment: Have you tried this? I think it will install side by side and will not remove the old app.

Comment: Yes, it works. I also tried setting a different product name for the new application. The old application still gets replaced, and the shortcuts are updated with the new product name.

Comment: However I have not tried this with a signed application. I guess you have to use the same signing certificate, otherwise it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the update as mandatory.
To mark an update as required, click Specify a minimum required version for this application in the Application Updates dialog box, then specify the publish version (Major, Minor, Build, Revision), which specifies the lowest version number of the application that can be installed.
This is the same as setting the minimumRequiredVersion attribute of the Deployment element in the deployment manifest; for example:

> < deployment install="true" minimumRequiredVersion="1.0.0.0">

Comment: Hmm.. first one to answer but still bounty gets awarded to answer which was posted later on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't attempted this route but its the assembly name and project name which is used to control this, if they are the same, you can update the version and publish over the top.  If you want these to be different then it will deploy a concurrent version.